# Is there a synonym for "name"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I think that "name" is one of the few words in English that doesn't have synonyms. It will be really interesting if it did have one. Now by "name", I don't mean "title" or "label", which can be used for anything (objects or organizations), I mean it as a usage for a human name.

In short, is there a word that can replace "name" in "what's your name"?

I thought "moniker" may have been a good contender. Though I hear that it means a nickname. But I don't know.

Comment: I realized that the word "appellation" can also be used for somebody's name.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one ....  sometimes, but not only, used for nicknames:

> ***handle***
>
> [google definition of handle](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=handle)
>
> verb (definition omitted)
>
> noun
>
> 1.
>   the part by which a thing is held, carried, or controlled.
>
> *"the pan features helpful lifting handles"*
>
> 2.
>   *informal* **a name or nickname.**
>
> *"that's some handle for a baby"*

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the word `moniker` (sometimes`monicker`), although informal, qualifies as a synonym.

Some definitions:

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/moniker):

> *informal* 
>   **A name:**
>
> *‘his real moniker is Dave Kennedy’*

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/moniker)

> *noun, Slang.*
>   1.
>   **a person's name, especially a nickname or alias.**